# Copy/move files with NSFileManager to a path, automatically creating intermediate directories

Tags: iphone, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I want to to copy a file with `NSFileManager` at a given path.
I am hoping the file manager to create potentially non-existing intermediate directories on the fly. But apparently it doesn't do so.

Do I really have to manually break up the path, get my file's parent folder and create that with `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` myself?

Does anyone have a nice implementation for that? Thanks to all!

Answer (score -3):

NSFileMager provide this API to copy from one path to another try this:-

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: And if you want to create the path then use the below which will give you path NSString *path=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

Comment: Also there are various thing you can pass for example say you want your path in desktop then use NSDesktopDirectory inspite of passing NSDocumentDirectory etc.